# How do unanswered questions on meta effect the site?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm wondering if unanswered questions in meta effect the overall site ranking on percentage of questions answered.  I know the current ranking is sub 90% and that's not good, we need to get it higher.  If unanswered meta questions effect that percentage, perhaps we should get some answers going on them?

As well, if questions that are legacy unanswered (old ones) were to be deleted does the percentage of unanswered questions change for the overall response numbers or is that a ding against the site regarding unanswered questions?

Comment: I've always wondered whether the "unanswered" included ones which had an answer, but no answer was selected as *the answer*. I would bet Meta questions don't count to the site total, but they are probably factored in to the overall transition model.

Comment: I suspect this question may be better to ask over at Meta.

Comment: @Paul  I suspect you might be right.

Comment: The irony that this question is unanswered...

Comment: Oh sweet irony.

Comment: I love that this is still unanswered.

Comment: @George   The irony continues.  I'd like to see this question go out for years and be unanswered.   :)